# How to distribute thread for each section in parallel sections

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a question about how to distribute threads:
There are two sections inside a omp parallel sections, one is a for loop(can be changed to a while loop), it is used to analyze my data and insert them to a deque, this section is time consuming thus I need most of the threads do this task simultaneously. While another section is to consume the deque, save the data to disk and pop the deque. The second section must be done with ONLY one thread, because it is not time consuming and I need it to be done serially. The second section is designed to consume the deque whenever it is not empty.

Here is a scratch of my code,I know it is not correct but I do not know how to fix the code to let it do exactly as what I want. Thanks in advance:

```
std::deque < outCCRec > CCRec_list;
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(12)
{
            #pragma omp section
            #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) private(i)
            for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
            {
                 // Need 11 thread to do this section  
                // Analyze data and save it to the CCRec_list deque
            }

            #pragma omp section
            {
                // Need one thread to do this section, 
                // Consume the data in CCRec_list deque and save them to 
disk, and then pop the deque
            }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a mutex or other synchronization primitive protecting your `deque`? Otherwise, you might get two threads trying to insert at the same time, or other similar possibly bad scenarios... Unless you happen to have a fully thread-safe implementation of `std::deque` there...

Comment: I've already add a critical directive before manipulating the shared deque, thus I think this may not be a problem. @twalberg